# Fetch someUrl.html not working in React Native / Expo?

Tags: react-native, fetch, expo

I'm trying to use fetch to get the contents of the HTML page in React Native, and I'm running it on expo, here:

https://snack.expo.io/@abalja/hellofetch

Basically the code is nothing special, uses 'fetch' which does work for loading .json files, but I can't get it to work for .html files. It just silently fails, and I don't even get an error logged. I'm not sure if this is Expo or ReactNative issue.

```
const url2 = 'http://www.spiegel.de/sport/fussball/nations-league-italien-trifft-in-der-nachspielzeit-polen-steigt-ab-a-1233219.html#ref=rss'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){

    console.log('did mount, fetching: ' + url2)
    fetch(url2)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response) // 1
          return response.text()
        })
        .then((responseText) => {
          console.log('fetch text', responseText) // 2
          // return responseText.movies;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

At 1 I get the response logged:

```
{type:"default",status:200,ok:true,headers:{…},url:"http://www.spiegel.de/sport/fussball/nations-league-italien-trifft-in-der-nachspielzeit-polen-steigt-ab-a-1233219.html",_bodyInit:{…},_bodyBlob:{…}}
type:"default"
status:200
ok:true
►headers:{map:{…}}
url:"http://www.spiegel.de/sport/fussball/nations-league-italien-trifft-in-der-nachspielzeit-polen-steigt-ab-a-1233219.html"
►_bodyInit:{_data:{…}}
►_bodyBlob:{_data:{…}}
```

At 2 I get absolutely nothing logged.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, I get both the response logged and the text. Could you provide more information about what you want to retrieve from that Website?

Comment: Did you try on expo or on device?

Answer (score 5):

Promise syntax is confusing to me, so I changed into async-await:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    console.log('did mount, fetching: ' + url2);
    try {
        let response = await fetch(url2);
        let text = await response.text();
        console.log(text)
   } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
   }
}
```

It works! You can check it here: https://snack.expo.io/@aazwar/fetch-url

Comment: console.log(text) still does nothing, but yes the text appears in the UI. Why is that?

Comment: I just realized that console.log(text) does nothing, but it even doesn't log "did mount, fetching"

Comment: This worked for me. I was forgetting 'let text = await response.text()'.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are parsing your [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/fi/docs/Web/API/Response) as `text` and not as `json`, and then trying to call object-key against `string`. Basically what you have at that point is string which looks like json. Parse your response with `.json()`-method instead.

`return response.text()` should be therefore `return response.json()`

to reconstruct your code

```
// With .then()
fetch(url2)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then((responseJson) => {
      return responseJson.movies;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });

// OR with await/async
const response = await fetch(url2)
const json = await response.json() // As '.json()' is async function as well
return json.movies
```

I would succest using await/async since syntax is much more cleaner and it  start's to be way to go.